# Product from max to min

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, summation, products

```
Product[f[i], {i, 1, 4}]
```

gives us

```
f[1] f[2] f[3] f[4]
```

Is there any way I can take the product it will give something following

```
f[4] f[3] f[2] f[1]
```

I need it for matrix multiplication in reverse order.

Comment: mybe with NonCommutativeMultiply @@ (Reverse[List @@ (f[1] f[2] f[3] f[4])]) /. 
 NonCommutativeMultiply[A_, B___] :> HoldForm[Times[A, B]] ?

Comment: What about `Dot@@Table[f[i],{i,4,1,-1}]`? (Note the step size of `-1` to go backwards)

Comment: @user49047 worked Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the values using `Map` (i.e., shortcut `/@`)

```
f[#] & /@ Range[4, 1, -1]

{f[4], f[3], f[2], f[1]}
```

To get the `Dot` product of the `f`'s you can `Apply` (i.e., shortcut `@@`) the `Dot` function:

```
Dot @@ (f[#] & /@ Range[4, 1, -1])
```